# How to add ' character to the key and values in TIniFile

Tags: delphi, ini

I am using Delphi XE3. I use `TIniFile` to write to an `.ini` file. One of the problems is when I use `WriteString()` to write a string to the ini file. Although the original string contains `'`, `TIniFile` will remove it after writing into the ini file. What makes things worse is when the string contains both `'`and `"`.

See below:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Str, Str1: string;
  IniFile: TIniFile;
begin
  IniFile := TIniFile.Create('E:\Temp\Test.ini');

  Str := '"This is a "test" value"';
  IniFile.WriteString('Test', 'Key', Str);
  Str1 := IniFile.ReadString('Test', 'Key', '');

  if Str <> Str1 then
    Application.MessageBox('Different value', 'Error');

  IniFile.Free;
end;
```

Is there a way to make sure `TIniFile` will write `'` around the values?

**Update**

I try to escape and unescape quote ", as well as = in my ini file, as below:

```
function EscapeQuotes(const S: String) : String;
begin
    Result := StringReplace(S, '\', '\\', [rfReplaceAll]);
    Result := StringReplace(Result, '"', '\"', [rfReplaceAll]);
    Result := StringReplace(Result, '=', '\=', [rfReplaceAll]);
end;

function UnEscapeQuotes(const S: String) : String;
var
    I : Integer;
begin
    Result := '';
    I := 1;
    while I <= Length(S) do begin
        if (S[I] <> '\') or (I = Length(S)) then
            Result := Result + S[I]
        else begin
            Inc(I);
            case S[I] of
            '"': Result := Result + '"';
            '=': Result := Result + '=';
            '\': Result := Result + '\';
            else Result := Result + '\' + S[I];
            end;
        end;
        Inc(I);
    end;
end;
```

But for the following line:

'This is a \= Test'='My Tset'

ReadString will only read the 'This is a \=' as the key, not 'This is a \= Test'

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Escape_characters

Comment: Your code nowhere uses `'`. Are you sure writing is the problem? As per [GetPrivateProfileString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprivateprofilestring) when the value "is enclosed in single or double quotation marks, the marks are discarded" - the read should be the problem, eh?

Comment: Try using `TMemIniFile` instead. It works around various shortcomings of `TIniFile`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Sorry but I try TMemIniFile and it cannot solve my problem.

Comment: `Str := '"This is a "test" value"';` is an invalid string, because it is improper punctuation. It contains two strings (`"This is a "` and `" value"`), with the orphaned word `test` appearing outside quotes. The rule for quotes is that if the phrase is between two double-quotes, the embedded quotes should be single quotes (e.g., "This is a 'test' value"), and if the outer quotes are single then the inner quotes should be double (e.g., `'This is a "test" value'`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot write anything in an INI file. But you can escape any character that is not allowed or handled in a special way by Windows.

The simple code below implement a basic escape mechanism (could be optimized):

```
function EscapeQuotes(const S: String) : String;
begin
    Result := StringReplace(S, '\', '\\', [rfReplaceAll]);
    Result := StringReplace(Result, '"', '\"', [rfReplaceAll]);
end;

function UnEscapeQuotes(const S: String) : String;
var
    I : Integer;
begin
    Result := '';
    I := 1;
    while I <= Length(S) do begin
        if (S[I] <> '\') or (I = Length(S)) then
            Result := Result + S[I]
        else begin
            Inc(I);
            case S[I] of
            '"': Result := Result + '"';
            '\': Result := Result + '\';
            else Result := Result + '\' + S[I];
            end;
        end;
        Inc(I);
    end;
end;
```

Use like this:

```
procedure Form1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Str, Str1: string;
  IniFile: TIniFile;
begin

  IniFile := TIniFile.Create('E:\Temp\Test.ini');
  try

    Str := '"This is a "test" for key=value"';
    IniFile.WriteString('Test', 'Key', EscapeQuotes(Str));
    Str1 := UnEscapeQuotes(IniFile.ReadString('Test', 'Key', ''));

    if Str <> Str1 then
      Application.MessageBox('Different value', 'Error');

  finally
    IniFile.Free;
  end;

end;
```

Of course you may escape other characters as well, for example control characters like CR and LF. You've got the idea :-)

Comment: Sorry but your code does not work for '=' equal.

Comment: @alancc then please update your question to include an example of `=` not working.

Comment: @alancc Sorry but it work with equal sin as well. I tested the code with Str := '"This is a "test" for key=value"'; Where do you insert the equal? Show an example by updating your question with ALL cases where it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally I use your solution, with a variant. I use \x3D to escape the equal sign, thus equal sign will not appear in the escaped string any more.